# Test for convergence of the series $\sum\limits_n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Which comparison for the comparison test would we use to see if $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ converges? Or should I be using the integral test?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \log\left(\frac{(2n)^2}{(2n+1)(2n-1)}\right)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1480093/convergence-of-sum-n-1-infty-log-left-frac2n22n12n-1-right)

Comment: Compare with ${1\over{n^2}}$ by using l'Hospital

Comment: Avoid L'Hospital (as usual) and follow the answer below.

Comment: Use the equivalence $\ln{(1+x)}\sim {x},\;\; x \to {0}.$

Comment: Even just the upper bound is enough: $0 \leq \ln(1+x) \leq x$ for $x \geq 0$.

Answer (score 8):

You may use that $\ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{n^2}\right) \underset{n \to \infty}{\sim} \frac{1}{n^2}$, and that $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges.

Comment: $\sum 1/n^2$ converges by an Integral test, also by the Cauchy Condensation test.

Comment: Also there's this neat trick : for $k \ge 2$ we have $\frac{1}{k^2} \le \frac{1}{k(k-1)} = \frac{1}{k-1} - \frac{1}{k}$, so $$\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{k^2} \le 1 + \sum_{k = 2}^n \frac{1}{k-1} - \frac{1}{k} = 2 - \frac{1}{n+1} \le 2$$

Answer (score 2):

Use
$x > \ln(1+x)
> x-x^2/2
$
for
$0 < x < 1$.

Then
$\sum_{n=1}^{m} \ln(1+\frac{1}{n^2})
<\sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{1}{n^2}
$
and this sum converges
and is bounded by
$\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

To get a lower bound,
$\sum_{n=1}^{m} \ln(1+\frac{1}{n^2})
>\sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{1}{n^2}
-\frac12\sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{1}{n^4}
\to \frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{\pi^4}{180}
$.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested, the value of the sum is $\log\left(\frac{\sinh \pi}{\pi}\right)$, using the fact that $$\sin x = x\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2 \pi^2}\right)$$

Comment: What kind of mathematics is used to prove the product? Can one systematically factor other Taylor expansions in similar ways?

Comment: @mathreadler https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem

Comment: Ah, beautiful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way, using the integral criterion:

$$\sum_{n \geq 1} \log \left( 1+ \frac{1}{n^2}\right) \leq \int_1^\infty \log \left( 1+ \frac{1}{x^2}\right) dx $$

Making the change of variables $y = \frac{1}{x^2}$ we obtain
$$\sum_{n \geq 1} \log \left( 1+ \frac{1}{n^2}\right) \leq \int_1^\infty \log \left( 1+ \frac{1}{x^2}\right) dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \log \left( 1+ y\right) \frac{1}{\sqrt{y^3}}dy.$$

Taylor's formula for $\log(1+y)$ around 0 tells us that $\log(1+y)\approx y$ when $y\approx 0$. So

$$\int_0^1 \log \left( 1+ y\right) \frac{1}{\sqrt{y^3}}dy \approx  \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}dy < \infty.$$

Hence, the sum converges.